# How to merge columns in Excel but with strikethroughs and colours

Tags: r, excel, vba, merge

This question might be too specific for Excel to handle but I'll ask anyway...

I have 2 columns containing letters. The 1st column is supposed to be 'Before' and the 2nd is 'After'.

The first request is that I want to merge them into one column with no repetition.

The second harder request is if the letter exists in 'Before' but not 'After' then it should be struckthrough. If it wasn't in 'Before' but was in 'After' then I want it to be coloured. If it was in 'Before' and remains in 'After' then it shouldn't have any changes.

The following is an example of what I want:

[image]

Is this possible? I thought about using R and then writing to Excel but I realised that Excel by default just removes any formatting when writing cells... If there is an R to Excel solution I would happily accept that. VBA solutions are also good if conventional Excel cannot handle this.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in Excel VBA. You would use the `.Characters` property of the Range object to decide about formatting the characters in the combined column.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help

```
Sub Strikeandcolor()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        beforeword = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        afterword = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
    
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = beforeword & afterword
    
        len_bw = Len(beforeword)
        len_af = Len(afterword)
    
        For j = 1 To len_bw
    
            char_value = Mid(beforeword, j, 1)
            mypos = InStr(afterword, char_value)
            If mypos = 0 Then
                 With ws.Cells(i, 3)
          '  .Value = beforeword & afterword
                .Characters(j, 1).Font.STRIKETHROUGH = True
                End With
            End If
    
        Next
    
        For j = 1 To len_af
            char_value = Mid(afterword, j, 1)
            mypos = InStr(beforeword, char_value)
            If mypos = 0 Then
                With ws.Cells(i, 3)
          '  .Value = beforeword & afterword
               .Characters(j + len_bw, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                End With
            End If
    
        Next
        
    Next
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: This code is not quite right.
It does colour correctly but it does not strikethrough the correct values. However, it is certainly very useful and I will play around with it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you check it now, it may strike the right characters

Comment: I tested using a simple example and it seems to work. If I wanted to use words instead then it doesn't work for obvious reasons. Is there a way to tell it to understand the spaces between words?

Comment: Yes we need to find the spaces between words and check if the word is present or not .Here i used for a character, same logic we can use but we need to modify to length of the word